# google maps in laravel project

Tags: php, google-maps, laravel

I am workin on laravel project in which i have to integrate google maps. I am using this package https://github.com/alexpechkarev/google-maps for google maps . I install this package and get api key from https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials . then I just follow the usage of this package for example i write the code in my controller

```
$response = \GoogleMaps::load('geocoding')
        ->setParam (['address' =>'santa cruz'])
        ->get();
```

It giving me data in json encode formate but i dont't know what i do next . How can i display maps . can someone please give me proper example of this package via code i will be thankfull for that thanks in advanced

Comment: Can take a look googlMapper, that provide huge flexibilities. I use in my project without any trouble-
http://www.tisuchi.com/add-google-map-laravel-googlmapper/

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually implement the map on the front end in your views:

```
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js" async defer></script>

<script>
  function initMap() {}
</script>
```

Read this: https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/fundamentals/adding-a-google-map#introduction

Comment: ok now tell me where and how i will use the data that i get from above code that is in json formate

Comment: You should pass the json data you get in your controller to your view through a variable and use it there to manipulate the map.